# Performing an action after multiple Ajax calls have finished (async:false is set)

Tags: jquery, ajax, asynchronous

I have an array of youtube channel names:
var a = ["MyHarto", "vlogbrothers", "pbsideachannel"];

I'd like to iterate through each channel, query the Youtube Data API, and add up the total number of subscribers on each channel. My problem is that even with async set to false on the $.ajax call, the the subscriber count is printed out to the screen right away without waiting. Here's my code:

```
var subscriberTotalCount = 0; 
function grabStatsChannel() {
    $('#youtube-stats-ch').html("Working...");
    var myURL = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?";
    var a = ["MyHarto", "vlogbrothers", "pbsideachannel"];
    a.forEach(function(channel) {
        var query_params = {
            key : API_KEY,
            forUsername : channel,
            part : 'statistics'
        };
        $.ajax(myURL, {
            data : query_params,
            type : 'GET',
            async: false,
            dataType : 'jsonp',
            success : function(data) {
                $.each(data.items, function(i, entry) {         
                    subscriberTotalCount += parseInt(entry.statistics.subscriberCount);
                });
            }
        });
    });
    $('#youtube-stats-ch').html('');
    $('#youtube-stats-ch').append('Found' + subscriberTotalCount + ' subscribers.<br />');  
}
```

I've tried setting an ajaxcomplete function, that never seems to be fired. Suggestions? What I get right now is 0 subscribers printed out, even though I can see with logging that the Ajax calls are succeeding and the subscriber count gets set correctly in the end.

Is there a clean way to either block or do a final refresh?  I thought that setting async to false would work here.  Unfortunately, if I print the total out within the success function, the screen flickers a bunch as it updates with each total, which I'd like to avoid.

Comment: You can use jQuery's deferred methods like `.when()` http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple example from jquery site to manage multiple ajax calls...http://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/

```
$.when( $.ajax( "/page1.php" ), $.ajax( "/page2.php" ) ).done(function( a1, a2 ) {
  // a1 and a2 are arguments resolved for the page1 and page2 ajax requests, respectively.
  // Each argument is an array with the following structure: [ data, statusText, jqXHR ]
  var data = a1[ 0 ] + a2[ 0 ]; // a1[ 0 ] = "Whip", a2[ 0 ] = " It"
  if ( /Whip It/.test( data ) ) {
    alert( "We got what we came for!" );
  }
});
```

Comment: This is lovely!  I just tried it out & chains together nicely.  Thank you.